# How can I develop a task manager ASP.NET MVC application with Entity Framework and three layers architecture. Help me to set up authorization

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am trying to set up the authorization and roles in my project. The source code here:  https://github.com/KimSergey94/TaskTracker

1. The user is the table that contains `id`, `email` and `password` columns. Email column is used to find the password for the employee, manager and client entities
2. Employee can be a manager that can create tasks and assign it to another employee. Employee has `id`, `user_id`, `First name`, `last name`, `salary`, etc. Employee can create comments for `Status` table that has `message`, `IsCompleted` columns and inherits from `Task` table. Employee can see all tasks assigned to him.
3. `Manager` table has `id` and `employee_id`. Can create and assign tasks as well as comment on them
4. `Task` has `id`, `manager_id`, `employeeId` and `IsCompleted` attributes.
5. `Status` entity has `id`, `task_id` and `message` properties
6. `Comment` entity has `id`, `status_id` and `comment` properties
7. `Client` has `id`, `user_id`, `country`, `address`, `email` and `company name` properties
8. `Admin` has `id`, `email` and `password` attributes. Admin cannot delete, edit or create tasks but can delete their manager or employee. In this case, I think we need to delete the tasks having a relationship with such managers or employees. Not sure how to achieve such functionality probably will need a stored procedure or something else.

[image]

How can I develop basic functionality, make use of AJAX and create custom filters and stored procedures? I'd really appreciate the code snippets like the user manual thing approach

Help me with the registration, authorization and roles for the project.

I've added rolemanager section in the web config but getting an error

here is the code:

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="cookies" timeout="2880" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" />
</authentication>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="SecurityForm.Providers.CustomRoleProvider" /> 
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

</system.web> .

Comment: Well, the error seems pretty clear: the `HomeController` doesn't have a parameter-less constructor - and ASP.NET MVC needs that. So just add a parameter-less constructor to your `HomeController` ...

Comment: Oh ok but wouldnt it deteriorate the functions of the task service?

Comment: cause it the task service will not be instantiated

Comment: can you help with the project by providing code sample here?

Comment: of primary functions of the app

Comment: If you **must get** an instance of the task service when your  `HomeController` is instantiated,  then you must set up some form of **dependency injection** to handle this. Without it, you'll get these errors...

Comment: doing that in the web layer in global asax

Answer (score 0):

If you read the stacktrace carefully, you will easily find the problem.

Your application try to instantiate a `HomeController` but there is no constructor without parameters.

Comment: Yes. But for some reason I need to have that ITaskService interface for example.

Comment: Aby other help? I am quite frustrated that I need to develop this app and add more functionality in a week

Comment: The reason is you split your application in different layers. The `ITaskService` is your Business-Logic-Layer, which needs to be instantiated too. This one needs a `IUnitOfWork` which is your Data-Access-Layer, which needs to be instantiated too.

Comment: Then I can add reference and instantiate it as field or call inside the needed action of the controller? Or it's supposed to be in the business logic as well?

Comment: If it its no requirement, I would throw away all additional layers due to time concerns. Especially when its a small project or a project to get into programming.

Comment: it is one of requirements to have 3 layers arhitecture

Comment: its preinternship project for .net developer position in a company))

Comment: So how would i tackle instantiation of the IUnitOfWork?